# Can't run imagemagick convert in php system

Tags: php, imagemagick, system

I'm having this issue where I can run imagemagick command through command line, but when run through php system function, it doesn't work.

So if I run this command in console. it works

`/usr/local/bin/convert https://pixabay.com/get/54e4dd424d53a414f6da8c7dda793e7a133bd9e6514c704c7c277dd29249c050_1280.jpg -crop 855x558+213+139 /var/www/html/tmp/s1b0a.png`

but when I run it in php

`system("/usr/local/bin/convert https://pixabay.com/get/54e4dd424d53a414f6da8c7dda793e7a133bd9e6514c704c7c277dd29249c050_1280.jpg -crop 855x558+213+139 /var/www/html/tmp/s1b0a.png")`

it doesn't work. No error message is produced

php system() is enabled.

`echo "<pre>"; system("/usr/local/bin/convert -version"); echo "</pre>";`

gives me

`Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-28 Q16 x86_64 2020-08-29 https://imagemagick.org Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)  Delegates (built-in):`

Are there any other settings that's prevent php from working?

Comment: My first assumption is inadequate file permissions when running under PHP. The server might be capturing useful error messages so try redirecting standard error to standard output.  (Add  `2>&1` to the end of your `system` command line string - with a space separating it from your output filename of course. )  If that gives you any output, please add it to the question.

Comment: Thank you, it is permission issue. Running in command as root works, but when run in php it's running user permission which can't write to to the folder.

Thanks for your direction